Merging two partitions using GParted
I recently installed Ubuntu on my Windows 11 machine so I can dual boot. After playing around with Ubuntu for a while, I decided I wanted Windows 11 removed entirely, so I deleted all Windows partitions on my Ubuntu. Now I have 352 GB of unallocated space. I would like to merge the unallocated space with my Ubuntu partition, however I cannot do that since the unallocated partition comes before the Ubuntu partition.
GParted:


This question is similar to: How to resize partitions?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Suggestion: just format ext4 and mount in your /home like ~/Data

I do not prefer very large / (root) partitions, anyway, so suggestion of separate /home or /data makes sense. Sometimes if totally re-configuring drive easier to just totally reinstall & restore from backups. Data or separate /home does not have to be separate drive as shown in these examples: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

I use a single large / partition in some cases, and a relatively small / and separate /home in others depending on my needs. Both work. For new users I recommend a single large / partition as it is done during default installation.

Short answer replicating https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/289138
Boot your installation media, in "Try Ubuntu" mode.
This removes the restrictions which makes it impossible to modify the partitions you have in use on the NVME drive.
From there run gparted to move and resize the Ubuntu partition.
Backup? Nahh... that is being a coward! ;-)
